# Joomla module position with Yt framework

Tags: module, position, joomla-template

I am working with a Joomla 2.5 template called Sj_news25 - see the demo here http://demo.smartaddons.com/templates/joomla17/sj-news/

What I want to do is create a module position somewhere between the logo and the search box, so I can fit a language switcher flags there.  I have previously used a tutorial on http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position%3F and that has worked fine, but this template uses a so-called "Yt Framework" and when I look at the index.php file, I'm stumped.  Is there anyone here who could venture a guess?  Thanks!

```
<?php
/****************************************************************************************
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * Yt Framework
 ****************************************************************************************/

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'yt_template.class.php');
include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'frame_inc.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" <?php echo ($ytrtl == 'rtl')?'dir="rtl"':''; ?> lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>

<body id="<?php echo $yt->template; ?>" class="<?php echo $yt->isHomePage()?'homepage ':''; 
                        echo isset($_GET['option'])?$_GET['option'].' ':''; 
                        echo isset($_GET['view'])?'view-'.$_GET['view'].' ':''; 
                        echo $yt->getParam('sitestyle').' '; 
                        echo $ytrtl=='rtl'?'rtl'.' ':''; 
                        echo $yt->getParam('menustyle').' ';
                        echo 'fs'.$yt->getParam('fontsize'); ?>">

    <div id="yt-wrapper"><div id="yt-wrapper-inner1"><div id="yt-wrapper-inner2">
    <?php 
  // add mobile head                                       
    if( $yt->is_mobile ){
        include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'mobile_head.php');
    }    
  ?> 
    <a id="top" name="scroll-to-top"></a>
  <?php   
  foreach($yt_render->arr_TB as $tagBD):  if( $tagBD["countModules"] > 0 ){
    if( ($tagBD["name"] == 'content') ){ // Block content - #content ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $tagBD["id"]; ?>" class="<?php echo $yt_render->layouttype.$tagBD['class_content'];?>">
          <?php 
      // 
      if($tagBD['showDivTop']=='1'){ ?> 
            <div class="yt-main yt-div-top-1"><div class="yt-div-top-2"><div class="yt-div-top-3"></div></div></div>
            <?php } ?>
      <div class="yt-main"><div class="yt-main-in1"><div class="yt-main-in2 clearfix">
            <?php
        $countL = $countR = $countM = $countCL1 = $countCL2 = 0;
        foreach($tagBD['positions'] as $position):
          if( isset($position['column']) && $position['column'] == 'yt-col1' ){
            $countCL1++;
            if($countCL1==1){
            ?>
            <div id="yt-col1" style="float:left; width:<?php echo $yt_render->cinfo['w-yt-col1']; ?>;<?php echo $yt_render->cinfo['display-yt-col1']; ?>">
            <?php
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
              if($tagBD['count-yt-col1']==1){
              ?>
            </div>
              <?php
              }
            }elseif( $countCL1==$tagBD['count-yt-col1'] && $tagBD['count-yt-col1']>1 ){
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }else{
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
            }
          }elseif( isset($position['column']) && $position['column'] == 'yt-col2' ){
            $countCL2++;
            if($countCL2==1){
            ?>
            <div id="yt-col2" style="float:right; width:<?php echo $yt_render->cinfo['w-yt-col2']; ?>;<?php echo $yt_render->cinfo['display-yt-col2']; ?>">
            <?php
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
              if($tagBD['count-yt-col2']==1){
              ?>
            </div>
              <?php
              }
            }elseif( $countCL2==$tagBD['count-yt-col2'] && $tagBD['count-yt-col2']>1 ){
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
              ?>
            </div>
              <?php  
            }else{
              include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
            }  
          }else{
            include (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'block-content.php');
          }
        endforeach; //End foreach position of block content
            ?>      
      </div></div></div>

      <?php
      //
      if($tagBD['showDivBottom']=='1'){ ?>
      <div class="yt-main yt-div-bottom-1"><div class="yt-div-bottom-2"><div class="yt-div-bottom-3"></div></div></div>
      <?php } ?>

        </div>
    <?php
    }elseif($tagBD["name"] != 'content'){ // Block is not content
    ?>       
    <div id="<?php echo $tagBD["id"]; ?>">
      <div class="yt-main"><div class="yt-main-in1"><div class="yt-main-in2 clearfix">
      <?php 
      if( !empty($tagBD["hasGroup"]) && $tagBD["hasGroup"]=="1"){ // Tag Body has group
        $flag = ''; $openG = 0; $c = 0;
        foreach( $tagBD['positions'] as $posFG ):  $c = $c+1;
          if( $posFG['group'] != "" && $posFG['group']!= $flag){ 
            $flag = $posFG['group'];
                        if($openG == 0){ $openG =1;?>
                        <div class="group-<?php echo $flag.$tagBD['class_groupnormal'];?> clearfix" style="<?php echo isset($tagBD['width-'.$flag])?'width:'.$tagBD['width-'.$flag].'; ':'' ; ?><?php echo $float1;?>">                       
              <?php 
              echo $yt->renPositionGroup($posFG);  
              if($c == count( $tagBD['positions']) ){echo '</div>';}
            }else{
              $openG = 0;
            ?>
              </div>
                            <div class="group-<?php echo $flag; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $tagBD['width-'.$flag]; ?>; <?php echo $float1;?>">
            <?php 
              echo $yt->renPositionGroup($posFG);  
            }
          }elseif($posFG['group']!="" && $posFG['group'] == $flag){ 
                      echo $yt->renPositionGroup($posFG);
            if($c == count( $tagBD['positions']) ){echo '</div>';}
          }elseif($posFG['group']==""){ 
            if($openG ==1){
              $openG = 0;
              echo '</div>';
            }
            echo $yt->renPositionGroup($posFG);
          }
        endforeach;
      }else{ //Tag Body normal
        if(isset($tagBD['positions'])){ 
          if(isset($tagBD['autosize'])){
            echo $yt->renPositionNormals($tagBD['positions'], $tagBD["countModules"], $tagBD["limited"], $tagBD['autosize']);
          }else{
            echo $yt->renPositionNormals($tagBD['positions'], $tagBD["countModules"], $tagBD["limited"]);
          }
        }
      }
      ?>
      </div></div></div>
    </div>
<?php
    } // end elseif($tagBD["name"] != 'content')
  }
  endforeach;
    ?>
     </div></div></div>


    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
    <?php
  if( !$yt->is_mobile && $yt->getParam('showCpanel') ) {
    include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'includes'.DS.'cpanel.php');
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php /*}*/ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to file: your_template/layouts/layout-homepage.xml(or current layout) replace code:

> @logo
>   header1
>   by:
>   @logo
>   your_position
>   header1
>   You can find out more about Yt Framework here: http://www.smartaddons.com/joomla/templates/yt-framework

Comment: From an Anonymous User: Please refer this link http://www.smartaddons.com/forum/195-sj-news/2665-how-to-create-new-position